# Why method is not running in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I just runnung method getNewMessagesLong() in longPolling way:

```
function getNewMessagesLong() {
    pollingFishingStarts();
    $request = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "listenMessageLong",
        data: lastIncomingMessageLongJson,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('Long Fishing ends...');
            pollingFishingEnds();
            }, complete: getNewMessagesLong})
}
```

but line with pollingFishingEnds() is not running//
and line with console.log() is runnig ok

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: What is pollingFishingEnds()?

Comment: no error. Just  pollingFishingEnds() is not run. So  pollingFishingEnds() is another method in my JS document

Comment: which console.log is running? You have two console.logs. Could you please tell which one?

Comment: console.log('Long Fishing ends...'); is normally running

Comment: but method in next line is not running!

Comment: Maybe the function `pollingFishingEnds` is not running because it's not in scope?

Answer (score 1):

The `url` you have is `listenMessageLong`. This doesn't seem correct. If the url is not correct, then the ajax will never succeed and thus the success method will never fire.

Comment: listenMessageLong is correct. Thst's url on my SpringMVC controller and it correctry response to my client's ajax request